# How to Unshare a Windows 7 Machine?

Tags: windows-7, network-share

I have a *Windows 7 Enterprise* machine on one domain which is visible from a different domain and a different user, even though I disabled sharing.

At one point in time, the *Windows 7* machine had the `D:` drive (DVD) shared to the owner user account. The drive hasn't been shared for awhile.

From a separate domain with a separate user account, on 5 different *Windows Server 2012 R2* machines, I can see and have full access to the `C:` drive and all the mounted drives on the workstation. This domain has numerous other machines which do not see these drives.

On the workstation I have unshared the `C:` drive and from `Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings` I have turned off all the sharing options. I also went through some of the folders and chose `Share With Nobody`. I restarted the machine multiple times before and after these changes. I also restarted the servers which see the drives, with no luck.

How can I completely unshare this machine?

Comment: @slyboty Does the account you're logging in with on the Windows 2012 server have administrative rights on the domain the PC is on?

Comment: @Kate no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the **Windows Server 2012 R2** machines which were able to see and navigate the workstation's folders and files were being accessed remotely from the workstation using the **Remote Desktop Connection Manager** application.
This application has the ability to share local resources with the remote machines. Therefore, from **Server Properties -> Local Resources** I unchecked the `Drives` box. This has removed the ability of these machines to access my local drives from the workstation.
Also, these local drives were available to the machines only through this application ran from this one workstation. No other accounts from the machines had this kind of access.

Answer (score 1):

Windows systems automatically shares the root of every hard drive on the machine as $ (so you get C$, D$, A$, etc). These shared are secured in such a way that only members of the local administrative group can access them.

Considering your case I have 3 suggestions for you,

1. You can temporarily unshared these administrative shares. That is, open computer management-> Shared folders->Shares. Here you will see all the shares are listed here. If you wish to unshared C drive select C drive -> All tasks-> Stop sharing. Now you will have a warning message which indicates that the share is created for administrative purpose only and if we continue to unshared it this will be recreated when the service is restarted or the computer is restarted. Click ‘Yes’ to continue and confirm once again by selecting ‘Yes’ on shared folders window.
   Now you can try to access the share from another machine and you will not be able to access those shares. But as indicated earlier this is a temporary solution and the shares will recreate automatically when the service ‘Server’ (This service is responsible for file, print and named-pipe sharing over the network) is restarted from services console or the particular computer is restarted.
2. As described earlier the administrative shares are allowed by default for local administrator users of computer, in your case windows 7. As you already know that the ‘Domain administrators’ are members of ‘Local administrator’ group you can remove it from your windows 7 computer you can get rid of this problem. Follow the below step to achieve it.

   On windows 7 computer open computer management-> Local users and groups-> Groups-> Administrators. From this group remove the group ‘Your domain\domain admins’ and any other user which is not relevant and apply the changes. Restart the computer and check the share status.

*This is the best solution and recommended for your purpose.*

3. If this still doesn’t resolve the issue. You can disable administrative shared permanently by following below steps.
   Open registry editor-> Click through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SOFTWARE | Microsoft | Windows | CurrentVersion | Policies| System`.  Now find out the registry and "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" edit the value to ‘0’. Once it is completed restart the computer and check the status.
   Note: If the registry "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" is not existing on the location you can create it as ‘DWORD (32-bit) Value’ and add the value. If you want to enable admin shares in future change this registry value to ‘1’.

Comment: I've tried all 3 steps at least once and no change. The drives are still visible.